# routing errors in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I'm getting this error in my rails app:

> No route matches {:action=>"edit",
>   :controller=>"parties"}

In my routes.rb file I have this set:

```
resources :parties
```

Under the directory views/parties/show.html.erb my view for show.html.erb contains this line:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Party Details", edit_party_path %><br />
```

THIS WORKS. However, under the directory views/users/show.html.erb it contains this line:

```
<%= link_to "edit parties", :controller => 'users', :action => 'edit_parties' %>
```

Inside the edit_parties.html.erb I have a loop that prints out the user's parties and a link to edit them. that link looks like this:

```
<li><h2><%= link_to party.title, edit_party_path %></h2><%= party.description %></li>
```

This is where the error occurs. Why does edit_party_path not work here, but it works above? Is it because edit_party_path inside edit_parties.html.erb has no ID for it to grab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your diagnosis is correct.

Try this instead (note the argument to edit_party_path):

```
<li><h2><%= link_to party.title, edit_party_path(party.id) %></h2><%= party.description %></li>
```

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

It seems that in your show.html.erb, edit_party_path is able to infer the id somehow.

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware you could pass stuff into the path like that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your resource to the path

Try

```
<%= link_to "Edit Party Details", edit_party_path(party) %>
```